# ionic 2 Take the texts of a site

Tags: http, get, ionic2

I can't retrieve the text from the homepage of www.ecklipse.com to feed the home page of my ecklipse application.

```
ionic g provider EcklipseService
```

I can't do a service for it...

All the tutorials I saw, use API already the on the site
I also can't extract JSON with this page.
The tutorial that I test uses the reddit api
[my ecklipse app block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2gxw.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an API that generates the text/JSON for the website then you can't do a `http.get()` to it.

Is the site text mutable? Does it changes a lot or is it static?

If it's static simply copy the text, if not you can also copy but update the app everytime the text changes (it's a boring work, but is needed in that case).

Or create an API where you can make http calls and get the text. If you're new to this and don't have time/skills to create one, try using Firebase, it goes well with web/ionic 2 and is easy to learn.

Comment: If it can help www.ecklipse.com/rss.xml